# Serret's algorithm and Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Serret's algorithm(1848) proved Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares as follows:
$p\equiv1\pmod4, u^2+1=kp, 1\leqslant u<\frac{p}2$

$r_0=p, r_1=u$,  then  Euclidean Algorithm
$$r_0=q_1r_1+r_2$$
$$r_1=q_2r_2+r_3$$
$$...$$
$$r_{k-2}=q_{k-1}r_{k-1}+r_k,$$
where $ r_{k-1}>\sqrt{p}>r_k$.  then determine $t_k$ such  that $r_k\equiv ut_k\pmod p$  with  $1\leqslant |t_k|<\sqrt{p}$ ?
we get that  $r_k^2+t_k^2=p$

How to prove $ 1\leqslant |t_{k}|<\sqrt{p}$? thanks!

Comment: See this page for a hint: http://www.numbertheory.org/php/euclid.html